# Aligning selectOption in PageBlockSection

Tags: visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

me again.  So, take this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="clientsList"  title="Clients List" rendered="{!searchCriteria.Search_Type__c ='Clients List'}" columns="1">

    <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedUser}" size ="1" multiselect="false" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!userIDList}" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

    <apex:inputfield value="X" />
    <apex:inputfield value="Y" />
    <apex:inputfield value="Z" />

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

This still results in the Select List not being aligned to the input field.  Everywhere I read says that putting inside a pageblocksectionitem would work.  What am I missing?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!  I really appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing an extra element inside the `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` to fill out the "label" area. You see, an apex:pageBlockSectionItem actually generates a small two-column table to hold 1) the field label and 2) the field input. Your page should align correctly if you just do the following:

```
<apex:pageblocksectionitem>
    <apex:outputLabel value=" " />
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedUser}" size ="1" multiselect="false" >
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!userIDList}" />
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageblocksectionitem>
```